# About error when sending multiple requests

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

On Hyperledger Fabric v1, I am trying to throw multiple requests to the same channel at the same time.

But the following error came out.

> Error: EventHub has been shutdown

Is there a limit on the number of simultaneous execution of chaincodes?

If there is a limit, is there a parameter to increase it?

Kindly let me know why this happens.

Comment: will need a bit more context. This error is reported when the disconnect() function is invoked. Maybe you could share more of the logs? You might also share the steps you took so we can reproduce.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried following. Multiplicity:10 Execution time:30sec. As a result, Some of the requests succeeded and the others got the above error.

Comment: You are running the PTE tool then?

Comment: I am using "loadtest" node.js module.

Comment: sorry, been traveling overseas. I'll get someone who has more depth with that tool to respond

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score -1):

To give more clarity on this, The event hub stops after a given period of time and the endorsement takes more time for processing and once the endorsements completed, it'll throw an event. But before that the eventhub will timeout and wont be able to catch it. The best way to fix it is by increasing the timeout time in your connection profile

Comment: The author does already know that it crashed. S/he is explicitly asking if there is a way to increase the number of simultaneous executions.